# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

Given the following pandas DataFrame -

| **json_path** | **Reporting Group** | **Entity/Grouping** | **Entity ID** | **Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)** | **Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** | **TWR Audit Note** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | William and Rupert Trust | 9957007 | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Cash | - | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1] | Barrack Family | Gratia Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 55491732.66 | -0.971018847 | -0.971018847 | 11.52490309 | 55491732.66 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income | - | 18469768.6 |  |  |  | 18469768.6 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[1] | Barrack Family | High Yield Fixed Income | - | 3668982.44 | -0.205356545 | -0.205356545 | 4.441190127 | 3668982.44 |  |

I am trying to filter on rows that != `Cash` (`'Entity/Grouping'` column) and that have a blank value in `'Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)'` column, `'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)'` column or `'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'` column.
**Code:** I am trying to achieve this by the following code -

```
perf_asset_class_df = df[df['json_path'].str.contains(r'(?:\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}')]
perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash') & 
                        (perf_asset_class_df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)'] == '') or
                        (perf_asset_class_df['Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)'] == '') or
                        (perf_asset_class_df['Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)'] == '')]
return perf_asset_class_df
```

**Issue:** I am receiving the following error, which points to an issue with `perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')...`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\WILLIA~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18756/2689024934.py in <module>
     48     writer.save()
     49 
---> 50 xlsx_writer()

C:\Users\WILLIA~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18756/2689024934.py in xlsx_writer()
      1 # Function that writes Exceptions Report and API Response as a consolidated .xlsx file.
      2 def xlsx_writer():
----> 3     reporting_group_df, unknown_df, perf_asset_class_df, perf_entity_df, perf_entity_group_df = twr_exceptions_logic()
      4 
      5 #   Creating and defining filename for exceptions report

C:\Users\WILLIA~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18756/1522996685.py in twr_exceptions_logic()
      4 #   [LOGIC] FOR PERF. BY ASSET CLASS (EX. ILLIQUID) - STANDARD REPORT PG.4
      5     perf_asset_class_df = df[df['json_path'].str.contains(r'(?:\.children\.\[\d+\]){4}')]
----> 6     perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash') & 
      7                             (perf_asset_class_df['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)'] == '') or
      8                             (perf_asset_class_df['Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)'] == '') or

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1533     @final
   1534     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1535         raise ValueError(
   1536             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1537             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am having a terrible run of making some amateur mistakes, and wondered if someone can give me a hint where I'm going wrong?

Comment: using `or` compares 2 series as a whole, using `|` compares them element-wise, which is want you want to perform filtering. replace all your `or` conditions with `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|`, not `or` to combine boolean Series.

In your case you can simplify using comparison to empty string on a slice of all target columns and `any`:

```
m1 = perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')
m2 = (perf_asset_class_df[['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)', 
                           'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
                           'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)']]
                           .eq('').any(1)
                           )

perf_asset_class_df.loc[m1&m2]
```

*NB. Using named masks here for clarity*